# Heroku app goes down every few days for 10 - 30 minutes. Normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

It's a simple rails app.  It just uses the postgresql database and it doesn't do any http calls except for newrelic monitoring.  But once or twice a week I get an alert from newrelic that my app is down, and it lasts anywhere from 10 to 30 minutes.  Is this normal?

The logs just show a bunch of H12 Request Timeout errors, but nothing else.

This is not a free account, I have two dynos running.  This is not immediately after a deployment.

I've tried puma and unicorn, following all the guides out there for configuration.  In the case of puma, the heroku router eventually starts timing out on requests.  In the case of unicorn, unicorn itself starts timing out.

Comment: Is this a free heroku account?

Comment: without a deployment?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are seeing this as well. Spun up extra dynos in case it was a queueing issue, but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: I eventually switched to Unicorn.  I only saw unicorn timeout once, and it restarted itself. It's been solid for a couple weeks now.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running on a single dyno application the dyno is idled after a long period of inactivity. Its possible and likely that New Relic is reporting this as downtime. If it takes a long period for your application to start up then it may have already reported it as down. All applications that run 2 or more dynos are never idled.

Comment: It's not that. New relic pings it every thirty seconds and keeps it alive. Also, I believe heroku knows/logs when idling happens, and I'm not seeing that. The heroku router sends the request to the app and the app never responds.